# OpenConnect VpnService for Android

Tags: android, android-vpn-service, openconnect

As I know there no API to support PPTP or L2TP connections inside android, so I switched to using openconnect (ocserv).

Is there any VpnService or API to connect to ocserv using Android?

I tried the sample app ([ics-openconnect](https://github.com/cernekee/ics-openconnect/blob/master/app/src/main/java/app/openconnect/core/OpenVpnService.java)) but the source code is deprecated and complicated to integrate.

Please don't suggest to switch using OpenVPN ;))

Comment: hey, did you find anything about this?

Comment: @Aligüvenç sadly no.